# Displaying values between times

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am trying to display the times that are between 03:00PM and 12:00AM within the same day. What can I do to get the desired results? I don't think my code should display anything with AM, but it does.

```
    select TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'HH:MI AM') from orig_table
    WHERE TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'HH:MI AM') > '03:00 PM'
    AND TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'HH:MI AM') < '12:00 AM'
    ORDER BY TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'AM'), TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'HH:MI');
```

```
    TO_CHAR(
    --------
    05:00 AM
    05:15 AM
    06:46 AM
    07:00 AM
    08:00 AM
    08:30 AM
    08:33 AM
    09:00 AM
    09:05 AM
    10:00 AM
    10:10 AM

    TO_CHAR(
    --------
    11:25 AM
    11:30 AM
    11:45 AM
    05:00 PM
    05:45 PM
    05:58 PM
    08:30 PM
    09:10 PM
    10:25 PM
    11:20 PM
```

Comment: Usually when doing boundary ranges, it's supposed to be lower-bound inclusive, upper bound exclusive (so `>= '03:00 PM' and `< 12:00 AM').  And do you want all times from _every_ day, or do you want just some specific date?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are converting the values to a character type, which means comparisons are done alphabetically. That way, `'05:00 AM'` **is** greater than `'03:00 PM'`.

Several ways to fix this. One is converting to character, but using 24h based time:

```
select TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'HH:MI AM') from orig_table
WHERE TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'HH24:MI') > '15:00'
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'HH24:MI');
```

Notice that you do not need to check for before midnight doing this way.

Additionally, you want to extend it to, say, 1AM in the next day, you'd have to start using whole dates portion. Also, use the `BETWEEN` keyword in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean midnight

```
select numtodsinterval(orig_time-trunc(orig_time)) as time
from orig_table
WHERE numtodsinterval(orig_time-trunc(orig_time)) > interval '15' hour
/
```

where there's no need to check for hour < 24

If you mean midday

```
select numtodsinterval(orig_time-trunc(orig_time),'day') as time
from orig_table
WHERE numtodsinterval(orig_time-trunc(orig_time),'day') between interval '12' hour and interval '15' hour
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'HH:MI AM') from orig_table
    WHERE TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'HH24:MI') > '15:00'
    AND TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') <= '23:59:59'
    ORDER BY TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'AM'), TO_CHAR(orig_time, 'HH:MI');
```

Comment: That will leave out something that happened at 23:59:59 :)